# C# WPF TextBlock Visibility doesn't change after StoryBoard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, visibility

I have a WPF application with a button, that when clicked executes a function that turns the visible property of   a TextBlock to Visible:

```
        savetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(savetxt.Visibility.ToString());
```

txt.Visibility.ToString());
When the TextBlock turns visible, a storyboard that makes it fade in and out starts:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="savetxt" Visibility="Hidden" Text="Hello">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

The first time I press the button, MessageBox.Show shows Visible, and the storyboard starts animating successfully. However, when I press the button the second time, MessageBox.Show shows Hidden and nothing else happens.
could anyone help me figure out why savetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; doesn't change the visibility after the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set storyboard from code.

### xaml

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="savetxt" Visibility="Hidden" Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"  Content="Test" Height="25" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

### code

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            savetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

            animation.From = 1.0;
            animation.To = 0.0;
            animation.Duration = new Duration(duration);

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, savetxt.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
            // Add the animation to the storyboard
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

            // Begin the storyboard
            storyboard.Begin(this);

            MessageBox.Show(savetxt.Visibility.ToString());
        }
```